# Error in Ubuntu 19.10: "Not Available - 802.1x Client Failure"

Tags: wireless, 19.10

Today, I encountered a wifi problem problem:

> Error in Ubuntu 19.10: "Not Available - 802.1x Client Failure"

I'm not able to connect to any Wi-Fi, what should I do?
[image: screenshot]